# Establish MQTT SSL connection with Pure Lua Library

Tags: ssl, lua, mqtt

I'm trying to activate ssl in my MQTT Connection. I'm using the Pure Lua MQTT Library in additon to that i installed the luasec module to establish a safe connection. The modul is i being reconized from the compiler and should work.

This is my current code:

```
local client = mqtt.client{
  uri = "localhost",
  username = "test",
  password = "test1",
}

client:ssl({
  mode = "client",
  protocol = "tlsv1_2",
  options = "all",
  key = "..."
  certificate = "..."


})

client:connect()
```

As a broker I use the Mosquitto Broker. The connection and the user authentication works.

However, I can't find a suitable configuration in the documentation how to connect SSL. The above example prints the error code

```
lua5.3: ./mqtt.lua:764: attempt to call a nil value (method 'ssl')
stack traceback:
    ./mqtt.lua:764: in function 'connectMQTT'
    /MQTT.lua:43: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Obviously, the object returned by `mqtt.client` does not have `ssl` method.  What does the documentation say about this?

Comment: Documentation doesnt say anything about it